# can rails re-creating default unit test and fixtures files, based on current schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, scaffolding

Is there a scaffold or other command that will generate from scratch the test/fixtures and test/unit files based upon the current schema?

A rails 3.0.3 app has no unit tests or fixtures yet, but has been through several migrations for several tables and have quite a few fields. So the default files in test/fixtures and test/unit that were created some time ago are very much out of date. Rather than re-created them manually based on the schema, can I re-run some scaffold command?

(I found `rails generate integration_test` but didn't see anything to re-create the test/unit and test/fixtures.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[By looking at the current code on Rails, no.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/test_unit/model/model_generator.rb)

Edit: This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591722/how-to-generate-fixtures-based-on-my-development-database).

I also recommend something like [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) instead of fixtures.