# How do I dump active record fixtures in development database using a declarative method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I want to dump fixtures in development environment but targets selected models -- with specific associations. I am lazy at filling out generated fixtures manually and I want existing relationships in my local database to be preserved so that test contexts will have valid data. I saw this [stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591722/how-to-generate-fixtures-based-on-my-development-database/73261859?noredirect=1#comment130700680_73261859). The answers guided me to a solution but my use case of using a declaration of models and their association needs a bit different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this tool:

```
module Tools
    class FixturesGenerator

        attr_accessor :tenant, :limit
        # An array of specific model names as symbols.
        # or a hash of record names and relationships as you would pass to <model>.includes(...)

        FIXTURES = [
            
        ].freeze


        def initialize(options = {})
            options.each do |key, value|
                send("#{key}=", value)
            end
        end

        def run
            send(:clear)

            ActsAsTenant.with_tenant(self.tenant) do
                save_model_as_yaml(self.tenant, 'tenants')
                FIXTURES.each do |item|
                    if item.is_a?(Hash)
                        item.each do |key, value|
                        generate_model_yaml(to_model_class(key), value, { limit: self.limit })
                        end
                    else
                        generate_model_yaml(to_model_class(item), nil, { limit: self.limit })
                    end
                end
            end
        end


        

        protected

        def to_model_class(name)
            name.to_s.singularize.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join('').constantize
        end

        def fixture_path(name)
            "#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/#{name}.yml"
        end


        def clear
            build_fixture_names.each do |name|
                name = name.to_s.pluralize
                path = fixture_path(name)
                if File.exists?(path)
                    File.delete(path)
                end
            end
        end


        def build_fixture_names
            add_fixture_name([], FIXTURES) + [:tenant]
        end

        def add_fixture_name(list, item)
            if item.is_a?(Hash)
                item.each do |key, value|
                    list << key
                    list = add_fixture_name(list, value)
                end
            elsif item.is_a?(Array)
                item.each do |x|
                    list = add_fixture_name(list, x)
                end
            else
                list << item
            end
            list
        end

        def generate_model_yaml(model_class, associations = nil, options = {})
            limit = options.fetch(:limit, 0)
            table_name = model_class.table_name
            query = model_class
            
            unless associations.nil?
                query = query.includes(associations)
            end

            query = query.order(created_at: :desc)

            if limit > 0
                query = query.limit(limit)
            end

            records = query.all

            save_collection_as_yaml(records, table_name)

            save_associations_delegator(records, associations) unless associations.nil?
        end

        def save_associations_delegator(records, associations)
            if associations.is_a?(Hash)
                associations.each do |key, value|
                    save_associations(records, key)
                    local_records = records.collect {|d| d.send(key)}.find_all {|c| !c.nil? }
                    save_associations_delegator(local_records, value)
                end
            elsif associations.is_a?(Array)
                associations.each do |name|
                    save_associations_delegator(records, name)
                end
            else
                save_associations(records, associations)
            end
        end

        def save_associations(relation, name)
            table_name = name.to_s.pluralize

            items = relation.inject([]) do |list, record|
                model = record.send(name)
                if model.nil?
                    list
                else
                    if model.respond_to?(:length)
                        list = list + model
                    else
                        list << model
                    end
                end
                list
            end
            save_collection_as_yaml(items, table_name)
        end

        def model_attributes(model)
            blacklist_attributes = %w[created_at updated_at deleted_at]
            attrs = model.attributes.reject {|k, v| blacklist_attributes.include?(k.to_s)}
            attrs.keys.inject({}) do |env, key|
                env[key] = attrs[key].to_s
                env
            end
        end

        def for_yaml(model, table_name)
            h = {}
            key = "#{table_name.singularize}_#{model.id}"            
            h[key] = model_attributes(model)
            h
        end


        def collection_for_yaml(collection, table_name)
            h = {}
            entry_prefix = table_name.singularize
            collection.each do |model|
                key = "#{entry_prefix}_#{model.id}"
                h[key] = model_attributes(model)

            end
            h
        end

        def save_collection_as_yaml(records, table_name)
            File.open(fixture_path(table_name), "a+") do |f|
                f.write collection_for_yaml(records, table_name).to_yaml
            end
        end

        def save_model_as_yaml(model, table_name)
            File.open(fixture_path(table_name), "a+") do |f|
                f.write for_yaml(model, table_name).to_yaml
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This has been of great help to me preparing for specific expectations and I hope some other person finds this useful